# Android log in and download csv file

Tags: android, download, login-script, autologin

I am writing an Android app and I need to download a csv file for a graph.  I am not sure if I need to either put the two columns to two array strings or import them to the DB then just query.  I am leaning towards just putting them to strings since the csv file will change constantly.

My two issues are:

1. I need to log into a specific URL to populate the CSV with the correct data such as http://myurl.net/protect/module_graph.htm?log=02.  That will populate the file http://myurl.net/protect/data1.csv with the data for the correct item.  Changing the log=02 to log=03 or any other number changes the content of the data1.csv file.  When I pull up the first URL in a web browser it pops up a window asking for basic authentication.  How do I need to call the URL to send the username and password with the request?
2. I need to get the CSV file downloaded and have the two columns output as strings so the graphing code can just read the data from the strings.  I think I know how to download it but should I store it to the SD card and then output the data or just open the file from the web and then output the data?  Also how do you tell it to put each column to an arraystring?

Any help is appreciated.  Code examples or links to tutorials or other options are much much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never say it, but I assume you are developing an Android app:

1. Use HttpClient GET with [authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html): an [example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java).
2. Again use HttpClient GET and [look at the reply](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java).

Comment: lol yea sorry, I am writing a free app for monitoring an aquarium controller. It outputs an RSS feed that I currently have showing in the main screen. It also logs certain things like temps, Ph, salinity etc. Now I want to be able to select the tempurature and see a graph created from the CSV. The RSS is not in an area that needs authentication but the csv is. I am going to go check out the links now. Thanks!

Comment: HA! I just figured out that if I use http://username:password@myurl.net:8383/blahblahblah I can access the data. I was overcomplicating it lol.  Now I just need to know how to get the two columns from the csv file into strings.